# Windows Forms, Timer calling event when timer starts

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I'm trying to create a timed task program (think Reminders app for Apple but with timers), and I'm trying to implement the timer. The timer starts and the event works fine, but for some reason, the timer event gets called right after starting the timer, rather than after the specified interval. This is my code for setting the interval:

```
 newTask.timerTime = float.Parse(timeInput.Text);

newTask.Initialize();
switch (timeInput.Text)
{
    case "Seconds":
        newTask.timer.Interval = (int)newTask.timerTime * 1000;
        break;
    case "Minutes":
        newTask.timer.Interval = (int)(newTask.timerTime * 1000) * 60;
        break;
    case "Hours":
        newTask.timer.Interval = (int)((newTask.timerTime * 1000) * 60) * 60;
        break;
}
newTask.timer.Enabled = true;
newTask.timer.Start();
```

And this is my code for creating the event (and `Timer.Tick`):

```
public void Initialize()
{
    timer.Tick += new System.EventHandler(OnTimerEnd);
}

//Timer event
private void OnTimerEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new ToastContentBuilder()
        .AddArgument("action", "viewConversation")
        .AddArgument("taskid", 1)
        .AddText("Your timer is up!")
        .AddText($@"Your task, {taskName}, is now completed! Great job!")
        .Show();

    timer.Stop();
    timer.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: The `On*` named methods are traditionally the methods that raise events, not the pones that handle events. Your `OnTimerEnd` method should be called something like `Timer_Tick` to follow the standard convention.

Comment: So what is `newTask.timerTime`?

Comment: Based on the code in your question `newTask.timerTime == 0`.

Comment: Calling Start/Stop as well as setting Enabled is redundant btw. Here's [the code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.windows.forms/winforms/managed/system/winforms/Timer.cs,becea5bbd879c9b1,references) for start: `public void Start() { Enabled = true; }`

Comment: That would make sense if timerTime is 0, but I’m pretty sure I set it to a value that the user inputs above the code snippet. I’ll edit the code snippet to show it

Comment: And I did both Start/Stop and Enabled because I didn’t know what would actually start or stop the timer, so I just did both for now. I’ll change it now though

Comment: ??? What is being entered into the "timeInput" TextBox? You are converting it to a float in this line, `newTask.timerTime = float.Parse(timeInput.Text);`...but then expect it to match with "Seconds", "Minutes" and "Hours" in this other line, `switch (timeInput.Text)`?

Comment: Oh, wait. That's the problem. I mistyped it: that makes a lot of sense. Thank you!